# #pragma warning disable ignored inside array initializer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I was trying to create a small define to work around [this bug in `QITABENT`](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1587319/shlwapi-h-qitabent-throws-warning-c4838-conversion-from-dword-to-int) and I noticed peculiar behavior of the `#pragma warning (disable: ...)` statement.

In the following code the define `QITABENT` generates warning `C4838`

```
static const QITAB qit[] = 
{
    QITABENT(MediaPlayerCallback, IMFPMediaPlayerCallback)
};
```

I can easily suppress this warning, this works:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4838 )

    static const QITAB qit[] = 
    {
        QITABENT(MediaPlayerCallback, IMFPMediaPlayerCallback)
        //{ 0 },
    };
    return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);

#pragma warning( pop )
```

Now I wanted to make a define `QITABENTEX` which automatically suppresses the warning generated by `QITABENT`. But it seems impossible because when I write the following code the warning `C4838` is **not** suppressed.

```
    static const QITAB qit[] = 
    {
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4838 )
        QITABENT(MediaPlayerCallback, IMFPMediaPlayerCallback)
#pragma warning( pop )
        //{ 0 },
    };
```

*How does the compiler interpret this code in such a way that the warning is not suppressed?*

This probably has to with when the definition for `QITABENT` is fully resolved.

(Note that I'm not really interested in making the above code work, I'm just really curious how its interpreted by the compiler)

**Addendum**:

Regarding the close vote and clarification: I got into a discussion with someone giving a shotgun/link-only answer, presumably only reading the question halfway through (since the question explained how to use `#pragma` in a macro which is not what I'm asking) now that answer got (self) deleted and I got a close vote for being unclear. So let me reiterate my intentions with this question:

- This question is not about finding a `define` to suppress this warning
- This question is not about how to suppress a warning in VC++ in general
- This question is about trying to understand what happens with the three lines of suppression code in the last code sample. Why do they not have effect in that exact position (in an array initialization) but do have effect outside the array initialization? This probably boils down to answering how and when the pragma statements and macross are resolved.

Comment: Please post the entire `C4838` warning message generated by this piece of code.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the warning is irrelevant (and doesn't change when I move the pragma statements) the interesting bit is why the pragma is ignored at that particular spot :).

Comment: are you sure the warning (C4838 is a narrowing conversion warning) is not in the `return QISearch(...)` line (in your first suppression example), instead of in the actual struct definition?

Comment: Note that standard C has `_Pragma` but Microsoft C has `__pragma` instead (per [`__pragma` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)).  However it is spelled, it appears that the pragma operator (as opposed to preprocessor directive, `#pragma`) does not help.

Comment: It is up to the compiler to interpret pragmata; it does it however it likes.  If it doesn't do it the way you'd like, you're almost certainly stuck with it.  You can try reporting the issue to Microsoft (the compiler vendor), but the chances of change as a result are slim to negligible, I fear.  It may be that the suppression can only be turned on before the braces of the initializer, or only before the `=` of the initializer, or it may need to be before the start of the declaration.  There could be reasons for any or all of those choices (which you might not always agree with).

Comment: Have you considered something as gruesome as `QITABENTEXEX(static const QITAB qit[] =  {, QITABENT(MediaPlayerCallback, IMFPMediaPlayerCallback), })` which passes the before and after material to the macro, allowing you to use `_Pragma` (`__pragma`) in the right places?  Note that this is dire — horrendous — but it might work, which would be about the only excuse for using it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah its really weird that #pragma doesn't seem to stick after '{'. I do not want to change it but I was wondering why. Might not be able to find the answer to that. I've considered all kinds of gruesome stuff and I've settled for something similar to your suggestion. But I wasn't really after a fix, more an explanation (probably why you posted this as a comment :) ).

Comment: I wonder if the same happens in GCC, might try tomorrow to see what happens :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initializer list terminates with the closing curly bracket `}`, and that is where warning is generated.

Try this:

```
static const QITAB qit[] =
{
    QITABENT(Derived, Base)
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4365 )
}
#pragma warning( pop )
;
```

[edited]
Per `Mr.C64`'s comment below, corrected the order of parameters in `QITABENT(Derived, Base)`.

Comment: Ah that's an interesting way to place the suppression code. Surprised that works! Gives me some insight in how everything is resolved.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the code in the answer, and that should be `QITABENT(Derived, Base)` (or `QITABENT(ClassName, InterfaceName)`).

Comment: I didn't want to edit your answer out of respect; I just wanted you to fix the typo. I found your answer useful and upvoted it.

Comment: I appreciate that; corrected the code in my answer.